# How to add custom css to the leads tab

Tags: lightning

In my custom tabs i simply add the following code to the component:

`<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.globalcss}"/>`

and it loads a static resource css file.
How can i load the same css file for "Leads" or "Contacts" tabs in lightning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot**.

`ltng:require` only works in context of Custom Lighting Aura Components. You can load static resources that can be used within your custom components. You cannot utilize this to *inject* styling into the Standard Tabs.

If you want to customize the look and feel of the Tabs, your only option is to create a Custom Lightning Aura Component and utilize that in a Custom Tab.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to customize the appearance of tabs, your have to create a custom Aura Lightning component and use it in a Custom tab.